# Reverse for 'article_detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['article/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, reverse

***I get frequent errors on different templates, I make a blog, and as soon as I clear my category_detail, then everything works, apparently there is an error in it***

category_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

{% if category_posts %}


  <h1>{{ cat }}</h1>


  <ul>
    {% for post in category_posts %}
  <l1><a href="{% url 'article_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    {{ post.category }}
     | {{ post.author }}
     {% if user.is_authenticated %}
     |-<small><a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">Редакт..)</a></small>
     {% endif %}
     <br/>{{ post.body|slice:":50"|safe }}
   </l1>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>


 {% else %}
 <h1>Извините страница не найдена</h1>
 {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**If I don't add the code and template for categories, everything works fine.**
enter code

views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats),
    return render(request, 'category_detail.html', {'cats':cats.title(), 'category_posts':category_posts})


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name= 'add_post.html'
    #fields = '__all__'

class AddCategoryView(CreateView):
    model = Category
    template_name= 'add_category.html'
    fields = '__all__'



class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'update_post.html'
    form_class = EditForm
    #fields = ['title', 'body']

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
#from datetime import datetime, date
from django.utils import timezone

class Category(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('home')


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='разные')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
    path('add_post/', AddPostView.as_view(), name='add_post'),
    path('add_category/', AddCategoryView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('category/<str:cats>/', CategoryView, name='category'),
    path('article/edit/<int:pk>', UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='update_post'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/delete', DeletePostView.as_view(), name='delete_post'),


]
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}


<h1>Articles</h1>


{% for post in object_list %}


<ul>
    <l1><a href="{% url 'article_detail' post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      <a href="{% url 'category' post.category %}">{{ post.category }}</a>
       | {{ post.author }}
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      |-<small><a href="{% url 'update_post' post.pk %}">Редакт..)</a></small>
      {% endif %}
      <br/>{{ post.body|slice:":50"|safe }}
    </l1>
</ul>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

***Help solve the problem, I've been sitting on it for the second day***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is in this line:

```
category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats),
```

You have put **comma(,)** sign at the end of line. So, `category_posts` is tuple of (<Post queryset>,) and in template you are iterating over this tuple rather than queryset. Change it to:

```
category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(pk)])
```

I think you need to write `pk` instead of `self.id`